# how to upload image,audio along with text to server in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to i phone programming.Using below code i am uploading image,audio,userid,caption.but here userid is not uploading.its giving response like userid is empty.

```
 UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Elephant.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,0.2);     //change Image to NSData
    NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tone" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file2];
    NSString* captionn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Aslam"];
    int x = 45;
    NSString *user_idd =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",x];
    NSString* mobile_tauky_idd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
    NSString * filenames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TextLabel"];
    NSLog(@"%@", filenames);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/index.php/api/uploadClass/uploadTauky/";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];   
    boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
          NSLog(@"%@", request);
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"caption\"\r\n\r\n%@", captionn] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //inputname
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n%@", user_idd] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //mobile_tauky_idd
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobile_tauky_id\"\r\n\r\n%@", mobile_tauky_idd] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //Image
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //Audio
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",audioData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  //  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"; filename=\"tone.mp3\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tone" ofType:@"mp3"]]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response : %@",returnString);

        if([returnString isEqualToString:@"Success ! The file has been uploaded"])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Image Saved Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        }
        NSLog(@"Finish");
```

Can any body tell me what mistake is there in this code

Comment: not really clear !!..
but why don't you put the userid in the request header or url ..
you need to config the web service also for that ...
about uploading images and so ..its alot easier to use ASIHTTPRequest for this task ..hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of server to app / app to server. I use this code to upload a photo.

```
-(void)uploadPhotoToServer
{
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myString]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:60];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundaryQkZe6RUJZ2xbzXLB";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picBLOB\" filename=\"image001.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:photoData]]; // <<< photoData is a UIImage
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
 queue:queue
 completionHandler: ^( NSURLResponse *response,
                      NSData *data,
                      NSError *error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         // no error... do something if needed.
     } else
     {
         // error... do something if needed.
     }
 }];
}
```

For text, I just include it in my URL. Like this:

```
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/4DACTION/"];
    [myString appendString:@"userID45"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myString]
                                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                            timeoutInterval:60];
```

My server side parses out the URL values.

Note: I use a 4D server. The 4DACTION is specific to that server and may not apply to your server.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake could be on your server.  Can you post the portion of the code where you parse these variables? (sorry, don't have the ability to comment on questions yet, so I have to "answer" to get clarification)